# Find variables common across groups for tidy data in R

Tags: r

I am looking to find common cases across groups in R, based on a tidy data set.

I could split the data sets and then join them, or use Reduce, but that seems laborious and I sure there must be a way to do this easily for tidy data, likely using `dplyr` and `group_by()`.

Here is an example:

```
data <- data.frame(case = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 
                   var = c(rep(1,4), rep(2, 4)))

  case var
1    A   1
2    B   1
3    C   1
4    D   1
5    B   2
6    C   2
7    D   2
8    E   2
```

What I want is the cases common across variables: `'B', 'C', 'D'`. I am thinking this should be easy but can't find an answer.

Comment: @akrun: Apologies, it was the first one that arrived. Best answer, removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'case', `filter` the groups having the number of distinct elements in 'var' equal to all the distinct elements in 'var', `ungroup` and get the `distinct` 'case'

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(case) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(var) == n_distinct(.$var)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct(case)
# A tibble: 3 x 1
#  case 
#  <fct>
#1 B    
#2 C    
#3 D
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .GRP[uniqueN(var) == uniqueN(data$var)], case]$case
#[1] B C D
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(data, names(Filter(function(x) all(unique(var) %in% x), split(var, case))))
#[1] "B" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by case, then grab the first row for those cases that have the correct number of occurrences.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(case) %>%
  slice(which(n_distinct(var) == n_distinct(.$var))[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, of course. Makes total sense. @akrun: Thanks for the elaboration

Comment: Actually, I ended up with a dataset that was more complex than the example laid out above. Essentially the number of unique cases was different to the number of unique cases in any group. As such the above code generated an empty dataframe. I ended up using @akrun base R solution.